# How to calculate suction caused by open water flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I have seen a couple of examples of overflow/underflow weirs being used in an aquarium to simultaneously filter surface scum and vacuum debris from a bare bottom tank.  I am trying to figure out how much flow I can expect through the underflow vs. the overflow depending on configuration.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Assuming I have a pump that actually returns 100 gallons per hour to the tank, with no opening at the underflow at point U, then 100 gph will be overflowing into the sump.  With a cross sectional area at point O of $A_O$ allowing water to return to the sump, I can calculate the velocity using $V_O=Q_O/A_O$ (where $Q_O=100$ gph and $A_O=0.5 in^2$).

$Q_O=100 gph = 0.0001051502778 m^3/s$
$A_O=0.5 in^2=0.00032258 m^2$
$V_O=0.0001051502778/0.00032258=0.33 m/s$

I figured I could use that in Bernoulli's equation to calculate the pressure differential between point X and the water flow above it.  However, when I have another opening of cross sectional area $A_U$ at point U, some of the flow will go through U, so $Q_O$ will no longer be $100 gph$, but will be $100-Q_U gph$.

When I ignored the above issues and tried to use Bernoulli's equation to figure out the velocity of water at point U, assuming the same overflow and underflow area $A_O$ and $A_U$, I came up with $V_O=0.33 m/s$ and $V_U=2.93 m/s$ which can't be right!

Starting with Bernoulli:

$P_O+\rho gh_O+\rho v_O^2 = P_U+\rho gh_U+\rho v_U^2$

I tried to solve for the velocity at point U:

$v_U=\sqrt{2/\rho*(P_O-P_U+gh_O-gh_U+\frac 1 2 v_O^2)}$

Assuming the following:
$\rho=1000 kg/m^3$ (water)
$g=9.80655 m/s_2$
$P_O=101300 Pa$ (standard atmosphere)
$h_U=0 m$
$h_O=0.2159 m$ (water depth of 8.5 inches)
Then I calculate $P_O-P_U=\rho gh_O=2177.23 Pa$.

With $h_U=0$, I get:

$v_U=\sqrt{2/\rho*(2177.23+gh_O+\frac 1 2 v_O^2)}$

$v_U=\sqrt{2/1000*(2177.23+(9.80655*0.2159)+\frac 1 2 0.33^2)}$

$v_U=2.93 m/s$

Which, through an opening $A_U=0.5 in^2$ means

$Q_U=v_U*A_U=2.93*0.00032258=0.00094 m/s=898 gph$!!!

What am I doing wrong here and what can I do to calculate the flow rate at point U?

How does the area at points O, U, and X affect this, and how could I modify them to create maximum suction from point U to point X?

I ultimately want to come up with a formula for this, but I really want to understand the concepts and how to combine/use them to arrive at the answers, so any insights are welcome.

Thank you!
-Rich

Comment: In my opinion, you need to add something that can introduce air bubbles at the bottom of the tube (?) on the left side of the large tank.  That would cause a siphon effect that would ensure that you get good flow up that tube as water is being carried over the weir.  In addition, if you regulate the air flow, you can control the ratio of underflow/overflow.

Comment: That is very true David!  It would create an air-lift "pump" which is one of my goals to remove from an undergravel filter to make it a slow-moving plenum instead.  But I don't know why I didn't even think about moving the airstone into the filter compartment.  I guess the only thing stopping me is that I want the width across X to be minimized to 1/8" to 1/4", and an airstone would require at least 1/2".  Do you know how to calculate the lift from that?

Comment: rjones54, no, I don't know how to calculate the lift from such a device, as you will have 2 phase flow.  2 phase flow can have various regimes, depending on the ratio of water/air going up the tube.  You will need to know the air flow rate and visually estimate the percentage of air in the flow to obtain an estimate.